# Is it possible to create Kinetic Typography effect with PhotoshopCS5 and AE4?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I am saying this because, I don't have Illustrator, so I want to know with what I can create Kinetic Typographics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Photoshop has a timeline animation feature. And After Effects is designed to create animation for video.

Comment: But kinetic typography is animated video.. So, I am going to need it video btw

Comment: Yes and both Photoshop CS5 extended and After Effects can create video.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create kinetic typography using both software titles, but I believe doing it in AE is easier, due to its preset animations.